# Deleting or Renaming a file using an open handle

Tags: winapi

The Windows API function [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function allows you to specific the desired access.  There are three options [read, write and delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  If you get a handle from CreateFile requesting Delete access how do you then delete the file using the returned handle?  The DeleteFile function takes the file name, not the handle.

Big Picture:
When saving files from my application I write out to a temporary file first, then delete the "real" file and rename the temporary file to the real name.  I have started to see problems with search indexers, or anti virus/spyware opening the file for reading but not allowing deletes.  This causes my save to fail when moving the files around.  I have changed my open code to request delete access to make sure I can delete the file when it comes time to save.

This all works fine but I still have a gap where a third party application could grab my file.  Since I have an open handle to both the temporary and real files I was looking for a way to perform the delete and rename functions using those handles.  The only option I can find is to close the handles and then call the DeleteFile and MoveFile functions.  Actually I am currently using the ReplaceFile API function to perform those steps, but it too has file names passed in and will not work unless I close my handles first.

I still need to support XP and cannot start using the new transaction file functions.  Is there any way to keep the files locked and still delete/rename them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Windows Vista there is that function [SetFileInformationByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365539%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), that can do what you need.

In previous versions of Windows there is no such function, but you have the equivalent native, not quite public function [NtSetInformationFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I have no experience with these functions, nor a Windows machine to test them, so I cannot show you the code, but that should not be so difficult.

The general disclaimer about native Windows functions apply, of course.